# Is it ok to feed my Cat Wotsits?

Tags: cats, diet

I have discovered that my Cat loves Wotsits, so I usually dish four or five of them to her whenever I eat a packet, though I am aware that certain human foods can be harmful to Cats, so was wondering if Wotsits are considered safe or harmful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manufacturer lists the ingredients on their [website](https://walkers-snacks.co.uk/walkers-wotsits):

> CHEESE FLAVOUR MAISE SNACK.
> Ingredients:
> Maize, Rapeseed Oil, Cheese Flavour [Dried Cheese (from Milk) (7%), Milk Lactose, Flavour Enhancer (Disodium 5'-Ribonucleotide), Acid (Lactic Acid), Colours (Paprika Extract, Annatto), Natural Flavourings, Salt, Potassium Chloride].

Apart from the fact that *none* of these ingredients are what a cat as obligate carnivore would naturally eat, there are a few things that would make me hesitant, especially the salt and the lactose. Salt in small(!) amounts is important for all animals, however, your cat food should meet all his needs and salty snacks can be harmful. And as many adult cats are lactose intolerant, the lactose may cause everything from slight discomfort to stomach cramps and diarrhea.

Of course it’s hard to pinpoint the border between not-exactly-good-for-you and outright harmful. I personally wouldn’t share these snacks with my cat.

Comment: 'Natural flavourings' could cover a variety of sins, including garlic. However as it's very far down the list, then its unlikely to be present at harmful levels